# Equivalent expression for "save for the rainy days"

Tags: expressões, tradução

The expression "save for the rainy days" talks about saving resources for times of scarcity.

Is there any equivalent expression in Portuguese?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's an expression in Portuguese (brazilian, afaik) which is

> Tempo de vacas magras

This can be literally translated as "Time of thin cows". It means exactly that it's a period with scarce resources, and it's a saying rather than a direct translation. I think it can be used in the context you mentioned, so:

> Guardar para o tempo de vacas magras.

As a real example, check [this news article](http://politica.estadao.com.br/noticias/geral,em-reuniao-dilma-diz-a-prefeitos-que-ano-sera-de-vacas-magras-imp-,1666341) which quotes Brazil's President Dilma Rousseff:

> ...a presidente Dilma Rousseff afirmou a integrantes da Frente
> Nacional de Prefeitos que este ano será de "vacas magras". De acordo
> com relatos de quem participou do encontro, a petista lembrou ainda
> que o contingenciamento do orçamento "será grande"...

Which can be translated as

> ... president Dilma Rousseff said to members of the Mayors National
> Front that this year will be of "*vacas magras*".  According to
> statements of the event's attendants, the *petista* also noted
> that the budget contingency "will be large".

**Edit**:

As pointed out by @ANeves in the comments, the inverse expression also exists:

> Tempo de vacas gordas

In that case, it means that a period has plenty resources. It's usually used in the context of highlighting that, even though the resources are/were plenty, they might not always be like that, so care should be taken or that this should be considered in whatever is being analyzed or described. For example:

> Ele estava muito rico no ano passado, mas era um tempo de vacas gordas.
>
> He was very rich last year, but it was a *time of  fat cows*.

Comment: Eu estava a escrever o mesmo termo sobre "vacas magras", no entanto a sua já explica +1

Comment: Eu também ia sugerir essa, mas você já respondeu bem. Acho que vale a pena adicionar a informação de que a origem dessa expressão é a [passagem bíblica sobre José e a interpretação do sonho do faraó](http://www.bibliaon.com/o_sonho_de_farao/) a respeito das setes vacas gordas e as sete vacas magras.

Comment: This answer would be improved by also including a short note on `tempo de vacas gordas`.

Answer (score 5):

Seria "**Poupar para os dias ruins**" ou "**Poupar para os dias maus**".

Era o que a formiga fazia e a cigarra não, no conto da Formiga e da Cigarra.

Comment: Mas isso não é uma expressão.

Comment: Pelo menos no Brasil conheço pessoas que usam expressões como essas.

Comment: uma expressão é uma forma de dizer algo de forma figurativa que não a forma normal. Tipo "Vou a casa jantar" não é uma expressão desse tipo. "Vou mudar a água as azeitonas" (quer dizer vou urinar) já é.

Comment: Eu vou "poupar para os dias maus" é uma frase normalíssima que se usa no dia a dia mas não é uma expressão figurativa.

Answer (score 4):

You could use:

> Portuguese: Guardar para época de vacas magras
>
> English: Save for the slender cow season

Or

> Portuguese: Poupar para o dia de amanhã
>
> English: Save for tomorrow

Don't be confuse for similar jargons like

- Guardar debaixo do colchão (store under your bed)
- Seguro morreu de velho (Insurance died from old age)

Those can be used to similar situations, but it's not as accurate translation of what you want

Comment: "Insurance died of old age" Acho que nesse contexto não dá pra traduzir "seguro" como "insurance". Não tenho uma sugestão melhor entretanto...

Comment: @mgibsonbr Não entendo o porque não seria uma tradução correta, visto que se trata de um seguro de vida ou similar. De algo asegurado por contrato. Mas fico ansioso por uma alternativa.

Comment: Minha interpretação dessa expressão sempre foi algo como "o homem prevenido tem tanta cautela que a morte só vai alcançá-lo na velhice" ([fonte](https://br.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20060817114703AAJ3H1l), [outra referência](http://3gbconsulting.com.br/blog/item/348-o-seguro-morreu-de-velho-o-que-significa-essa-frase)). Já vi algumas interpretações alternativas, inclusive usando o conceito de "fazer seguro", mas estas não fazem muito sentido pra mim. De todo modo, embora esteja seguro do significado da expressão, não sei traduzi-la pro inglês.

Comment: P.S. "died from old age" também me parece estranho. "died of old age" talvez? Hehe estou quase indo no English Language pra ver isso... :P

Comment: @mgibsonbr Sobre o "from" e o "of" você me deixou na dúvida. Minha interpretação da frase sempre foi a expressão em inglês "**Better safe than sorry**", mas não quis explicar com uma expressão e sim com a tradução direta do texto.

Answer (score 2):

[PT]
Existe uma usada em Portugal "poupar do riso para a chora" que é mais ou menos equivalente.

[EN]
In Portugal exists one "poupar do riso para a chora" that means "save when you are smiling to when you are crying"

Answer (score 1):

Hum, that’s a tough one. I believe a close translation would be *guardar debaixo do colchão*, literally to save it under the mattress. This was an old habit to save the money there, as there were no banks back then.

Comment: Acho que não...

Answer (score 1):

### Português

Basicamente refere-se a **economizar**, e não tem uma frase diretamente equivalente no português, você pode utilizar, entre outras, as seguintes frases:

- Economizar para o futuro.
- Poupar para tempos difíceis.
- Guardar dinheiro pensando no dia de amanhã.

---

### Inglês

Basically refers to **save**, and does not have an equivalent in Portuguese, you can use, among others, the following phrases:

- Economizar para o futuro.
- Poupar para tempos difíceis.
- Guardar dinheiro pensando no dia de amanhã.